# Why are tracks of the same title failed to uploaded to iCloud/iTunes Match?

Tags: itunes, icloud, music, itunes-match

[image: Tracks of the same title are failed to be uploaded to iCloud/iTunes Match.]

As the screenshot above shows, some tracks of the same title are failed to be uploaded to iCloud/iTunes Match.  Even they have different time lengths and belong to different discs.

For example, in the above screenshot, *SHOW* (3:32), the first track of the *second* disc has an iCloud status icon **Duplicate**, whereas *SHOW*  (3:30), the first track of the *first* disc is successfully uploaded to iCloud/iTunes Match.

Why does this situation happen, and how can I successfully upload these tracks to iCloud/iTunes Match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround for it.  iTunes seems to recognize tracks as different ones when they belong to different albums, even if these are the same audio.

So here's a way to fix it: make these tracks to temporarily belong to different albums, and when these tracks get successfully uploaded to iTunes Match/iCloud, merge these two albums into one album.  Here's a screenshot:

[image: The album view on mobile Apple Music app.]

These tracks are well uploaded to iTunes Match/iCloud so that they become visible to Apple Music for Android.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes match analyzes every song before uploading or matching it.

Even if a song appears to be different (different length, different title) it may in fact be the same song with a bit more silence at the end.

You can only upload songs that are different from the songs that you have uploaded before.

Is this second disc some kind of special edition of the first one?

Comment: Yes, the first disc contains original tracks released at 1975, and the second disc consists of remastered/remixed tracks of them.

Comment: Okay, this explains why iTunes Match does not recognize these tracks as different ones. It seems they sound too similar to iTunes. Only an analysis with an audio software can reveal whether these tracks are identical to each other (but the length if silence) or not. If they are different, however, you can try to encode them as ALAC (Apple lossless audio codec) files. Otherwise there is no way to force upload a song to iTunes Match without altering the file.

Comment: Unfortunately I failed to sync them despite I encoded them again to Apple Lossless.  Instead I've found another workaround!